# PHP getting an element

Tags: php

I have the following code. Which shows the webpage in php.

```
<?php


$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://jobseekers.direct.gov.uk/listjob.aspx?sessionid=94d5cfde-f7f1-40e9-bef6-2f587b4f04b0&pid=4&sid=421116805&p=1&so=1&rpp=20");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $curled=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
print_r($curled);
```

?>

I want to take the elements such as the job role out with cURL. I would like to make a list of all the roles, but I know how to do that from watching a tutorial. The job roles are embedded in the TD class

Comment: Post a sample of the HTML to be parsed. You will need to use a DOM parser like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: If it helps, Xpath is a really handy way to navigate elements contained within a DOMDocument. XPath and CSS Selectors basically do the same thing - identify html elements, but in this case an XPath query on a DOMDocument will return the required elements.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is actually HTML parsing, CURL is just for fetching the page. Check [this post out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php) as a good starter.

I would personally recommend using [SimpleDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) which enables you to apply css selector-based syntax on your HTML document.

Comment: Thanks! This is the first time im using PHP so im pretty clueless. Thanks for the links.